# Unable to start compute engine VM

Tags: virtual-machines, google-compute-engine

I am unable to start my VM. I keep getting error message below. I have tried unsuccessfully to restart for the past 12 hours.

Starting VM instance "centos-6-1" failed. Error: Google Compute Engine is not ready for use yet in the project. It may take several minutes if Google Compute Engine has just been enabled, or if this is the first time you use Google Compute Engine in the project.

If you have encountered such before please advise.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

1) Use an [incognito window](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95464?source=gsearch&hl=en) to access your Cloud Platform Console. Incognito mode will be helpful to avoid cache issues in the browser (if any).

2) Confirm that you have correctly set up [billing information](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/modify-project?hl=en&visit_id=637263179512467478-126775378&rd=1) and that there are no billing warnings in the cloud console.

3) If this is the first time you access your project, GCE API will be enabled when you access Google Cloud Console -> Compute Engine. It is normal that the system might take a couple of minutes to initialize.

4) You can also try to enable the [API](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/enable-api#enabling_an_api) directly. Google Cloud Console -> APIs and Services -> Library> Google Compute Engine API.

I hope this helps!